# How to Highlight Syntax with a RichTextBox and Disable Autoscrolling?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, syntax-highlighting

So I've spent about three days now searching the internet - Google, Stack Overflow, Microsoft's C# Documentation - and have yielded no helpful results.  My problem is that I've recently created a very flexible and fast syntax highlighting RichTextBox, which is held in a UserControl.  I created this using WinForms.

However, despite the speed and flexibility of my project, there remains one obvious and extremely obnoxious glitch.  This glitch is that my RichTextBox will automatically scroll...All...The...Time.  I do not want this autoscrolling to happen.  When I highlight the text, I'd like for the user to see no movement or transition, but only colored letters and symbols.  Here is the code that is affecting the syntax highlighting of my project:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);


    private void DoHighlight()
    {

        if (TextEditor.Text.Length <= 0)
            return;

        int visibleStart = TextEditor.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(1, 1));
        int visibleEnd = TextEditor.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(1, TextEditor.Height - 1)) + TextEditor.Lines[BottomLine].Length;
        int[] curSelection = new [] {TextEditor.SelectionStart,TextEditor.SelectionLength};

        LineCounter.Focus();
        SendMessage(TextEditor.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, (IntPtr)0, IntPtr.Zero);

        TextEditor.SelectAll();
        TextEditor.SelectionColor = TextEditor.ForeColor;

        if (parser != null)
            parser.HighlightText(this, visibleStart, visibleEnd);

        TextEditor.SelectionStart = curSelection[0];
        TextEditor.SelectionLength = curSelection[1];

        SendMessage(TextEditor.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, (IntPtr)1, IntPtr.Zero);

        TextEditor.Invalidate();

        TextEditor.Focus();
    }
```

After doing some debugging and using many breakpoints, I've determined that the autoscrolling does NOT occur until after the DoHighlight() method has finished and ran its course.

Also, I think it may be important to note that this DoHighlight() method is called whenever the RichTextBox's text changes right now.

Answer (score 0):

put DoHighlight() method in background process.
like this:

```
  BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
  bgw.DoWork += DoHighlight();
  bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

with this trick , your DoHighlight() method will run parallel  & autoscrolling can be occured.

also you can use this code in your DoHighlight() method:

```
Application.DoEvents();
```

this will pause your method and do other event, then return to your method.

Comment: "& autoscrolling can be occured"
But...I don't want autoscrolling to happen at all.  Is that what you mean by that?  And thank you for the help!  It is much appreciated!